# Get element from the list with

Tags: racket

I have a problem: The function must return randomly one of the elements of the list (that will be the car) and the cdr will be the relative frequency to get the car of that element.

```
(define (get-randomly ls)
   (list-ref ls (random (length ls))))

(define three-elements (list (cons 'a 1)(cons 'b 2)(cons 'c 3)))

(get-randomly three-elements)
```

I have get randomly all wrong so it return any random element not according to relative frequency. I need advice on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `get-randomly` uses a weight of `1` for all the elements since you are not using the weights.

So in order to do this you need to know the total sum of the weights. So you should make a helper so that:

```
(sum-weight '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3))) 
; ==> 6
```

Then you use `(random 6)` to get a number between `0` and `5`. Now you can iterate your list summing the weights as you go so that when you are above the number you got, that is the winning symbol.

So as an example lets say you get `4`. When you iterate you have `a` at `1`, `b` at `3` and `c` at `6`. `c` it is then. If you got `2` from random it would have been `b`.